# Microsoft SQL Server 2014 sequence

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

A brief description, I am building a VB.NET program from scratch including database. Therefore I am required to set the unique transaction ID for each table for example `header_id`, `detail_id`, `order_number`, and lots more that require any running increment number. I am upgrading from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2014 so that I can have a built-in `SEQUENCE` for the running number job.

My current situation (SQL Server 2005, VB.NET) is I am using a table to store all the running number and a stored procedure to execute the running numbers from my VB.NET program. For example in `Sales Order`, I will pass a hard-coded parameter to the stored procedure to find the value in the table and then increase the number by 1 and then insert it into the `Sales Order` table.

Before I start migrating the database and redesign the table structure, I would like to know if I am on the correct start, which means for each table I have to assign a specific sequence for it? Please guide.

Comment: It is not entirely clear why you feel that you must choose the unique IDs yourself instead of leaving this task to the RDBMS. Even with SQL Server 2005, you could have used `IDENTITY` columns and/or `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`s... do you know about these?

Comment: Hi stakx, I never deal with IDENTITY columns nor UNIQUEIDENTIFIER. Do you mind to shed some light?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually you do not need a `SEQUENCE` to generate unique, increasing identity values **for single tables**. Even with SQL Server 2005, you have two simpler options for that:

1. Define an `IDENTITY` column. For example:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE Orders
   (
       OrderId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
       …        -- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   );           -- very much like an unnamed sequence that START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1
   ```

   When `INSERT`-ing into this table, you do not need to specify a value for `OrderId`, it will be chosen for you by the RDBMS. The resulting IDs will be unique (but there is the possibility of gaps).
2. Instead of using integer number IDs, use GUIDs:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE Orders
   (
       OrderId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL DEFAULT (NEWSEQUENTIALID()),
       …
   );
   ```

   The `DEFAULT` constraint means you don't have to explicitly choose a value for `OrderId` when `INSERT`-ing; the RDBMS will generate a value for you.

   <sub>P.S.: `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` ensures that the generated GUIDs are steadily increasing. This is important if the GUID column is used for clustering (i.e. when you have a `PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (OrderId ASC)` constraint), as mentioned in a [comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31375999/microsoft-sql-server-2014-sequence/31376179#comment50731062_31376179). If the column is not used for clustering and it's only important that GUIDs are unique, but not necessarily increasing, then you can also use `NEWID()` instead.</sub>

Of course you can also use a `SEQUENCE`, but such a one has no added benefit over the above two (simpler) solutions. This changes when you have to create unique IDs **across several tables**, for example:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE OrderIds START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;

CREATE TABLE FlowerOrders
(
    OrderId INT NOT NULL DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR OrderIds),
    …
);

CREATE TABLE FlowerPotOrders
(
    OrderId INT NOT NULL DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR OrderIds)
    …
);
```

This way it should be impossible that `FlowerOrders` and `FlowerPotOrders` contain overlapping `OrderId`s.

Comment: For my case, I have multiple tables linked with IDs. For example, table `order_header` and `table order_detail` and the relationship is based on the column header_id in both tables.

Comment: When using a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` and a default constraint, I'd strongly recommend using the `newsequentialid()` function for the default, **especially** if that GUID column might end up being the clustering key

Comment: @4LeaveCover: Foreign key constraints have nothing to do with ways of guaranteeing the uniqueness of primary keys… Question: Do you know what `FOREIGN KEY` constraints are?

Comment: Is this a 1:1 relationship?

Comment: @marc_s: You're correct. I've added a note to my answer about this. I often take a different approach: I might have *two* ID columns in my tables, a (DB-internal) `INT IDENTITY` one (which is the clustering key, and which takes part in primary key / foreign key relationships), and an indexed `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ROWGUIDCOL` one (which applications may choose themselves, and by which they can search records).

Comment: @stakx I need a so called 'transaction_id' in my table, it must be a readable numeric value only and it must be unique in the table. I will need to query data based on that particular `transaction_id`. Therefore, according to you, I should use INT IDENTITY?

Comment: then you need a unique id for each table, but not a unique id that will spread across multiple tables. In that case, go with the simple int identity option (the first in this answer).

Comment: @4LeaveCover: Is `transaction_id` also going to be the primary key in that table? If so, the first code example in my answer applies (except that you also need to declare the column `PRIMARY KEY`). If not, then you might indeed have to resort to a `SEQUENCE`… unless you're willing to rethink your database schema design: you could set up a separate `transactions` table where `transaction_id` is the `IDENTITY` and `PRIMARY KEY`, and your other tables refer to this via a foreign key relationship).

Comment: @stakx From now on, I will amend every table to have the IDENTITY. But for the case where 1:many relationship, for example I have header_id (IDENTITY) and order_number in the table `order_header`, I will pass the order_number to the table `order_detail` therefore the relationship key is the order_number.  Table `order_detail` will have its own detail_id (IDENTITY) but only for transaction purpose. Is my approach correct?

Comment: @4LeaveCover: Please note that this is turning into an altogether different question. If you need help with how to define foreign key relationships, please ask a separate question. Thanks!